# Why is my create "Multiple lines of text" column missing append changes choice field even with versioning?

Tags: 2013, office-365, versioning, multiline-text-field, append-changes

SharePoint 2013/365

I'm trying to create a "Multiple lines of text" column with the append
changes setting. This requires that you have versioning turned on.

[What happened to multiple lines of text text format and append changes only settings?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47643/what-happened-to-multiple-lines-of-text-text-format-and-append-changes-only-sett) is not an answer.

[image: Create multiline text missing append changes choice field]

What am I missing?

[image: Versioning is turned on]

Comment: if you create a site column you will have the option 'Append Changes to Existing Text' Best Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content will be missing if you are adding this column to a document library or document set. Multi-line text fields act differently in Lists than in Libraries. If you don't get what you want here, you can create a custom list with a multi-line text field to hold the data and link it with a lookup field.

Hope this helps,
Mary Smith Greene

Comment: Very smart idea! It's a shame really because SharePoint used to be such a Swiss Army Knife. Now it's a baseball bat: dumb and blunt. Thank you!